# How to add List view with dynamic selection checkbox inside expansion tile in flutter

Tags: listview, checkbox, flutter, expandablelistview

I am facing problem to add listview with checkbox inside multiple ExpansionTile. Also, a checkbox has to be dynamically selection.

In this images I've created one expansion tile and inside I had put list tile with checkbox but when I am adding multiple expansion tile all are either selected or not selected based on value but i want to select user wanted value it means it should be dynamically

```
body: ExpansionTile(
      title: Text("Expansion"),
      children: _listViewData
          .map((data) => CheckboxListTile(
                title: Text(data),
                value: _isChecked,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isChecked = val;
                  });
                },
              ))
          .toList(),
    ));
```

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eHhq.png)

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var lovCountryServices = [
    {
      "services": [
        {
          "service_group_id": 2,
          "service_category": "B",
          "name": "Cat",
          "id": 6
        },
      ],
      "name": "A",
      "is_active": true,
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "services": [
        {
          "service_group_id": 3,
          "service_category": "B",
          "name": "Air",
          "id": 10
        },
      ],
      "name": "B",
      "is_active": true,
      "id": 3
    }
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            itemCount: lovCountryServices.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              var item = lovCountryServices[index];
              return ExpansionTile(
                title: Text("Expansion"),
                children: <Widget>[
                  CheckboxListTile(
                    title: Text(item['name']),
                    value: item['is_active'],
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {
                        item['is_active'] = val;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => print("sending to backend"),
            child: Text("SEND"),
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: if you don't want to use mapping u can use is_active property to checkboxes then post it to your backend with send button so you can save it to your database.

Comment: **@Furkan Aydin**  I appreciate your answer but can you please tell what happens when I am using multiple expand tile list? How can i able to select one item from first expand tile and second item from another expand tile list.

Comment: @RutvikGumasana I edited the answer. You need to use a new map for each expansion tile if they represented different list of values.

Comment: Can i do it with single map , Because i have lots of data so every time i have to make new map it's not possible practically. **Can you please Help me**

Comment: Can you share an example of your data? So i can work with it. @RutvikGumasana

Comment: "lovCountryServices": [
      {
        "services": [
          {
            "service_group_id": 2,
            "service_category": "B",
            "name": "Cat",
            "id": 6
          },
         
        ],
        "name": "A",
        "is_active": true,
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "services": [
          {
            "service_group_id": 3,
            "service_category": "B",
            "name": "Air",
            "id": 10
          },
         
        ],
        "name": "B",
        "is_active": true,
        "id": 3
      },
    ]

Comment: Sorry For Format. Here is My Json which i have to use for Data.
Just copy and paste this json into your IDE it will automatically formated. But please help me regarding this problem.

Comment: I edited the answer. Try to use your model's property for checkboxes. That's all I can do mate :)

Comment: Dear, Listen to me this json has two data first only name and second is inside there also name which is service name. ex 'A' and B' is main name which has to be displayed in expansion tile name and The 'Cat' and 'Air' is a subitem which is displayed inside checkbox list tile. 

Hope you understand :) Please Help me